# Macro Excel Cell to cell Countdown timer (CTimer to only display in Colum B next to Entry Made in Colum C )

Tags: excel, timer

Looking to make a Timer Entry

I am running the below but the entire Colum B has a timer running across the entire Colum B regardless if an entry was made or not.

Timer needs to run even if the file is closed, would this be possible?

I would really appreciate some help.

````
Dim StartTime As Date 'the start time of the countdown
Dim EndTime As Date 'the end time of the countdown
Dim TimerOn As Boolean 'a flag to indicate if the timer is on or off

Sub StartTimer()
    'this sub starts the timer when cell C is filled in but only on "C1"

    If Not IsEmpty(Range("C1")) Then 'check if cell C is not empty
        StartTime = Now 'get the current date and time
        EndTime = StartTime + TimeValue("00:01:00") 'set the end time to one minute later
        TimerOn = True 'set the flag to true
        Application.OnTime EndTime, "StopTimer" 'schedule the StopTimer sub to run at the end time
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "UpdateTimer" 'schedule the UpdateTimer sub to run every second
    End If
End Sub```

Sub UpdateTimer()
    'this sub updates the timer in cell B
    If TimerOn Then 'check if the flag is true
        Range("B1").Value = Format(EndTime - Now, "hh:mm:ss") 
'display the remaining time in cell B - but only in B1 and not B:B matching input of C:?

        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "UpdateTimer" 'schedule the UpdateTimer sub to run again on Enter

    End If
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    'this sub stops the timer when the end time is reached
    TimerOn = False 'set the flag to false
    Range("B1").Value = "Time's up!" 'display a message in cell B
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'this sub runs the StartTimer sub when cell C1 is changed, but id like to allow Colum C per Entry
    If Target.Address = "$C$1" Then 'check if the changed cell is C1
        StartTimer 'run the StartTimer sub
    End If
End Sub`

I am trying to make the Timer only display and run in Column B next to once column C of the cell data was and contains data,
````